# Reinstalling Ubuntu after botched installation

Tags: partitioning, reinstall

I tried to install Ubuntu recently (alongside Windows 7 64-bit on Lenovo Thinkpad T530), but I think I made the partition too small. I can't access Ubuntu when I turn the system on, and when I use the installation CD, it says that I already have multiple operating systems. How do I get rid of the ruined installation and make a new one?

Answer (score 0):

On the CD, there should be a "replace old ubuntu" option or something like that. This should meet your requirements.